# DatePicker Not Displaying Date

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on a application in which datepicker and textbox are in the same row. Based on the types change, I am collapsing the textbox and showing datepicker. The problem is when I make datepicker visible and the user selects the date, the date is not visible in the datepicker. The code I am using is

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="StackPanel3">
      <Grid>
        <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" Visibility="Collapsed"FontSize="32"  Width="405" Value="{Binding  RecordItem,Converter={StaticResource  RecordAndTypeFieldValueConverter},ConverterParameter=RE2, Mode=TwoWay}" ValueStringFormat="{}{0:d}"/>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding RecordItem,Converter={StaticResource RecordAndTypeFieldValueConverter},ConverterParameter=RE2, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="32"  Width="405" />
     </Grid>
 <Image  x:Name="i2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="0,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59" Source="/Icons/play.png" MouseLeftButtonUp="FieldTools_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In converter I am returning the string value to datepicker's value.

Comment: You should post the code of your converter too, i think that your problem is there. And Sams answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your textbox.text (string) value to DateTime value

For example, if you are using ddMMyy format (21JAN12), you would do this:

```
using System.Globalization;


     string date = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
                Date Time myDate= DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DatePicker1.Value = myDate;
```

Or you can specify any other format you would prefer for the date.

I changed the above code for TextBox1 and DatePicker1 as it is not a good idea to name these things by the control name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Windows Phone development, so just guessing. *Usually* that happens when the value of the control is not valid. Are you sure that `DateTimePicker` accepts `string` type value? To me, it should be `DateTime` type. If even yes, are you sure the *format* of the data is correct. ?